# difference between select distinct id and select distinct * in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

i tried with

```
select distinct ID  from  DB.TABLE;
```

it  returned unique ids in all records.

```
select distinct *  from  DB.TABLE;
```

it will return unique records by comparing all columns and  records  or what is functionality of "distinct *" ,i confused with functionality of distinct * .

Comment: `select distinct *` uses the tuple of *all columns* to determine distinctness. It's the same as `select distinct col1, col2, ..` for all columns in the table: the resulting columns returned will also be different accordingly. That is, the `*` with distinct is effectively the same difference as `select id` vs `select *` ..

Comment: In other words `distinct *` has no meaning. It's an oxymoron

Comment: if you have only Id column in your table then there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` means that there will be no duplicate rows in the resultset, duplicate meaning all columns have the same value in both rows. So yes, `DISTINCT *` means "select all columns and skip any rows where the values in all columns match some already included row".

Answer (score 0):

In first query, use have  used distinct on primary key of table, so it's obvious that you got all records. For better clarification use another field which is not unique in table.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `ID` is the PK or even a candidate key; such was not claimed in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Your first query means that you need distinct results based on values of a single column of a table. In your case it will return results based on distinct values of column named **ID** of table **DB.TABLE**.

But in case of your second query, it will return distinct results based on values of all columns.

For example consider below three records.

```
ID:01,col1:"some",col2:"one"
ID:01,col1:"some",col2:"two"
ID:02,col1:"some",col2:"two"
```

`select distinct ID from table` will return,

```
ID
01
02
```

as it check for distinct values only in column named ID.

`select distinct * from table` will return

```
ID:01,col1:"some",col2:"one"
ID:01,col1:"some",col2:"two"
ID:02,col1:"some",col2:"two"
```

all three records as there are no distinct records if you consider all three columns.

Simply put, it is like excluding duplicates based on a single column of a table vs excluding duplicates based on all columns of a table in expected result.

Comment: This answer is very hard to read. Please space things out and format code.