# Difference between SELECT * FROM TABLE vs SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE

Tags: sql

Is there a difference between the below two queries?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE
```

I was wondering if the above is the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

I do understand that when `DISTINCT` keyword is used with COLUMN NAME, it returns only unique values in that column but I want to understand what happens if you use `DISTINCT *` instead.

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51512236/difference-between-select-distinct-id-and-select-distinct-in-sql

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` returns unique rows, i.e. removes duplicates. The rows can consist of only one column (the case you mention), but they can also consist of a lot more columns.

Comment: As to the difference of the two queries: There exist only few if any tables in a database that allow rows that are exact duplicates. So in most cases, `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE` invokes an unnecessary search for duplicates and boils down to a mere `SELECT * FROM TABLE`.

Comment: [**DISTINCT | UNIQUE**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6): *Specify DISTINCT or UNIQUE if you want the database to return only one copy of each set of duplicate rows selected. These two keywords are synonymous. Duplicate rows are those with matching values for each expression in the select list.*

Comment: *I do understand that when DISTINCT keyword is used with COLUMN NAME, it returns only unique values in that column but I want to understand what happens if you use DISTINCT * instead.* **INCORRECT.** DISTINCT is applied not to column but to the whole row, to complete combination of all columns values. It is not a function. If in two rows there is at least one column where these rows contains different values then these rows are not duplicates, and they won't be collapsed into one row. Of course, if a table contains some PRIMARY KEY then DISTINCT in SELECT * makes no sense due to PK uniqueness.

Comment: There is an exclusion. In some DBMSs (for example, in PostgreSQL) there exists `DISTINCT ON ({expression})` which is an analog of (acts as) incomplete and non-deterministic `GROUP BY {expression}`. This is non-standard SQL extension.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table had only three columns, the two queries in question would be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 FROM yourTable
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM yourTable
```

The difference here is that should a given `(col1, col2, col3)` tuple appear more than once in the table, the first distinct query would only report it once, while the second query would report all duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * statement is used for returning all the values in the table column.

SELECT DISTINCT statement is used for returning only distinct (different) values from a column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have following

```
Create Table DataTable
(
   Id Integer,
   col1 Varchar(20),
   col2 Varchar(20)
);


Insert Into DataTable Values(1,'AAA','111')
Insert Into DataTable Values(2,'BBB','222')
Insert Into DataTable Values(3,'CCC','333')
Insert Into DataTable Values(1,'AAA','111')
Insert Into DataTable Values(2,'BBB','222')
Insert Into DataTable Values(2,'BBB','333')
```

When You Used Following Query

```
Select * from DataTable
```

The Following Output You See, its return all the rows

| Id | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 111 |
| 2 | BBB | 222 |
| 3 | CCC | 333 |
| 1 | AAA | 111 |
| 2 | BBB | 222 |
| 2 | BBB | 333 |

But When You Used Distinct With Select Query As Per Following

```
Select Distinct * from DataTable
```

The Following Output You See, its return only distinct rows means ignore the duplicate rows

| Id | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 111 |
| 2 | BBB | 222 |
| 2 | BBB | 333 |
| 3 | CCC | 333 |

Another Example Of Distinct With Two Columns

```
Select Distinct Id,Col1 from DataTable
```

| Id | Col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA |
| 2 | BBB |
| 3 | CCC |

Comment: These are good examples. I wouldn't call the first column ID, though, as it obviously isn't the table's ID, because there are duplicate values in the table. Calling it ID might lead to confusion.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner yes i know it's little bit confusion, but i have take ID just to explain properly

Answer (score 0):

table T has n column: C1, C2, .. Cn

`SELECT *` get all set {C1, C2,  ... Cn}

`SELECT DISTINCT *` get all unique set {C1, C2,  ... Cn}

For example

```sql
drop table furniture;
/
CREATE TABLE furniture (
    room      VARCHAR2(50),
    appliance VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO furniture VALUES (
    'BEDROOM',
    'BED'
);

INSERT INTO furniture VALUES (
    'LIVING ROOM',
    'SOFA'
);

INSERT INTO furniture VALUES (
    'TV ROOM',
    'TV'
);

INSERT INTO furniture VALUES (
    'ALL',
    'LAMP'
);

INSERT INTO furniture VALUES (
    'ALL',
    'LAMP'
);
```

Result of `select * from furniture;` is

[image]

Result of `select distinct * from furniture;` is

[image]